# Laravel: How to disable Tailwind's Optimization in local environment

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

Everytime I try to run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`, tailwind keeps purging unused styles in my local environment.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ]);
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
      './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
      './resources/js/**/*.vue',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`"tailwindcss": "^3.0.7"`

Comment: Is it using jit mode? I think that's the new default

Comment: @IGP yeah u'r right, PurgeCss is no longer being used in v3. Didn't know cuz I was still using v2 in my prev. projects. Thanks for mentioning it!